# Super won't call the overridden method in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a Java class called `Circle` which extends `JPanel`. All it does is draw a circle on the screen. It has a field int radius `r`, and a method `setRadius` to change that value and repaint . I also have a class called `ResizableCirle` with the method `resize()` which calls the `setRadius` method. `resize()` is also a method of JComponent so it gets overridden.

When I try and use `resize()` to change the circle with an `ActionListener` like this:

```
@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce) {
    JSlider source = (JSlider)ce.getSource();
    if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        circle.resize((int)source.getValue());

        repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error `incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Dimension`. dimension is the resize() argument for `JComponent`. why isn't it calling my `resize()` method?

I tried using `super` but then it says cannot find symbol.

Comment: What type is your `circle` variable?

Comment: The object was created like this: `Circle cirlce = new ResizableCircle();`

Comment: Then you need to either type your circle variable as a `ResizableCircle` or cast it to call the `resize` method. `Circle` does not have a `resize(int)` method on it.

Comment: Does your object Circle has its own `resize()` method that takes an integer? Otherwise it will try to call `Component` resize()

Comment: So `circle` is a `JPanel`, that's why.